# magento unsetChild breadcrumbs inside product view page through local.xml file

Tags: xml, magento, layout, breadcrumbs

Instead of removing all the breadcrumbs at the global level, I want to just `unsetChild` the breadcrumbs inside the product view page.

The following is my code but it does not work

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <child>breadcrumbs</child>
        </action>   
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I also tried the following but no luck either

```
<name>breadcrumbs</name>
```

And there is one more thing I notice, inside my catalog.xml file the layout for product view does not call the block of the breadcrumbs at all. The following is the code. If there is other handle calling the breadcrumb block where could it be?

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!--
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
            -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
                <!--<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>upsell_products</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>-->
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>additional</alias><title>Additional Information</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml</template></action>
                <!--<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>related_products</alias><title>Related Products</title><block>catalog/product_list_related</block><template>catalog/product/list/related.phtml</template></action>-->
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>                                        
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review">
                     <alias>product_additional_data</alias>
                     <title>Reviews</title>
                     <block>review/product_view_list</block>
                     <template>review/product/view/list_tab.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="magentothem.relatedslider" as="related_slider" template="magentothem/relatedslider/relatedslider.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
            </block>

                    <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
   <!--  <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference> -->

    <!-- <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="magentothem.relatedslider" before="-" template="magentothem/relatedslider/relatedslider.phtml"/>
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar"  name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" after="magentothem.relatedslider" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
        <block type="cms/block" name="banner_right" after="-">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>banner_right</block_id></action>
        </block>
        <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/> 
    </reference> -->

    <remove name="right.poll"/>
    <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I just found there is a <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?> in my 1column.phtml, Do I just remove it in this case?

Comment: in that case it will remove from all pages which are using `1column.phtml` as layout

Answer (score 0):

below code is working with magento 1.9.2. Put this code in your `local.xml`

```
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: no that removes all the breadcrumbs, check the category page.

Comment: I have 1.9.2 as well but it does not work for me. Might be an issue from theme files?

Comment: maybe. you are using custom theme or default magento theme?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your layout's `local.xml`

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

`catalog_category_view` is used for all the category pages.